# PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable"

Tags: mysqli, php7

estoy intentando utilizar mysqli en mis proyectos con php7. Vengo programando con php5, para que me entiendan.
Mi consulta es la siguiente: utilizando este código de consulta

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$name1 = $row['name'];
$email1 = $row['email'];
$direccion = $row['direccion'];
$provincia = $row['provincia'];
$ciudad = $row['ciudad'];
}
```

¿es necesario poner pada cada variable un if para que cuando el campo este vacio en la base no me muestre el error Notice: Undefined variable?
Ejemplo:

```
if(!isset($name1)){
$name = "";
}else{
$name = $name1; 
}
```

Muchas Gracias por la orientación
Un Abrazo

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario. Si una consulta devuelve campos con valores `NULL`, PHP los traduce a su propio tipo de datos interno [null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.null.php).

Si un valor, por ejemplo `$row['edad'];` fuese `null`, entonces:

```
> echo $row['edad'];
> // No pasa nada.
> 
> $edad = row['edad']; // Un valor null es asignable
>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda. Un Abrazo